# Using google colabs GPU for non ML tasks

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory

I want to know if and how I can use Colabs free GPU for non-machine learning related tasks. Specifically, I have a large amount of audio I want to calculate a number of complex values from using a package called scikit-maad.

I can run this in colab, but I can't figure out how to get this to run on the GPU (have turned it on in the notebook settings). I'm yet to find a tutorial online that is not related to ML

Can this be done? Are there any simple changes I can make to my code for this?
Can anyone recommend any resources or tutorials that can help?
Am I not grasping any key concepts?!

A simplified version of my code is:

```
#some imports
!pip install scikit-maad
from maad import sound, features, util
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd

#load my audio data e.g 100 one-minute audio tracks
uploaded = files.upload() #select wav files to be analysed.
```

```
#Calculate results using scikit-maad functions
ACI_results = []

for track in uploaded:
        wave, fs = sound.load(filename=track, channel='left', detrend=True, verbose=False)

        #compute spectrogram
        Sxx, tn, fn, ext = sound.spectrogram (wave, fs, nperseg = 256)

        #calculate ACI from spectrogram
        _, _ , ACI = features.acoustic_complexity_index(Sxx)
        
        #save result
        ACI_results.append(ACI)
```

Comment: Tensorflow has a very good API for audio processing and it uses natively your GPU here is a useful article https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-process-audio-on-your-gpu-with-tensorflow-2d9d91360f06

Comment: I need to use the very specific functions like features.acoustic_complexity_index() in the maad package, can this be done using tensorflow?

Comment: I found out from a colleague that the package I was using was not GPU compatible, so this would not provide any acceleration